# How to find what values are assigned to labels that where encoded using LabelEncoder?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

```
places = ['India','France','India','Australia','Australia','India','India','France']
```

> Here places are the DataFrame Series, now how can I find that which
>   label was encoded with values like India = 0 , Australia = 1 ,France =
>   2.
>   This is ok for few labels what if there are 100's of labels available
>   in a huge dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `classes_` attribute of your `LabelEncoder`. For example:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(places)
print(le.classes_)
```

The index of the label in `le.classes_` is the encoded value of the label. See another example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#label-encoding).